# How to make asp.net parse markup tag property as list

Tags: asp.net, parsing

Is there a way that I can extend asp.net to accept the markup

```
<c:MyControl runat="server" MyList="1,2,6,7,22" />
```

Where MyList is a List`<int>` or List`<string>` or even List`<someEnum>`?

So I want asp.net to parse automatically all lists (that can be parsed) generically.

I know I could take the way around it and make MyList a string, then parse that into a list, but then I just end up with more properties than I want tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anyway to get asp.net to to that automatically.  But if you're willing to go for a intermediate base class, then it's should be difficult.  i.e.:

```
 public class ListProcessorControl: Control {.....}

 public class MyControl : ListProcessorControl  {.....}
```

Now, you'd need some way to saying what king of list that is.  Either:

```
 <c:MyControl runat="server" MyList="1,2,6,7,22" TypeOfMyList="System.Int32" />
```

or make the base class generic:

```
 public class ListProcessorControl<T>: Control {.....}

 public class MyControl : ListProcessorControl<int>  {.....}
```